# Line up text over multiple lines under each other?

Tags: html, css

How to imitate this lay out? I can get the line breaks by putting the text in separate div-s, but then the left and right top line are also on separate lines.

```
<div>
        <div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 600;">11 <span style="border-left: 1px solid black"></span>     B </div>
        <div>Seats <span style="border-left: 1px solid black"></span> <span style="font-weight: 600;">Party's name</span></div>

    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VpW5x/1146/

Comment: do you have to use this order of html? or can I seggust a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is suggest to mark up your code

1. to set them in same line use `display:flex`
2. to create the line use pseudo element `:after`

```css
.wrap{
 display:flex; 
}
.border-right{
  position:relative;
}
.border-right:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    background: black;
    height: 85%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 100%;
  
}
.first{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.second{
 margin: 0;
}
.p-10{
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="border-right p-10">
    <p class="first">11</p>
    <p class="second">Seats</p>
  </div>
  <div class="p-10">
    <p class="first">B</p>
    <p class="second">Party's name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```